# React js not installed in ubuntu 20

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, npm, npx

I install node and create-react-app on my fresh ubuntu system. But got this error.

**Error**

> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...","shasum":"48db9f033'
> [image]

I uninstall node and create-react-app globally, then install it again.
Still got the same error.

**Tried**

Below commands, I tried to resolve this issue but nothing could be worked

```
npm cache clean --force

npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
```

**info**

I could not found this error log file in .npm/_logs. Because there is no file in this directory

[image]

**npm -v 6.14.8**

**node -v 10.19.0**

**create-react-app --version 3.4.1**

Answer (score 0):

Delete your package-lock.json file and have a try again.

Comment: I run this command **sudo rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json** but still got the same error. In which directory run this command?

Comment: In the root folder of your project, run rm package-lock.json, then npm cache clean --force and npm install

Comment: cannot remove 'package-lock.json': No such file or directory. **pwd /home/abd**. I run 
this command in this directory. I open the terminal  using ctrl+shft+t then run this command

Answer (score -1):

Try either running without `sudo` on a directory your user owns, or using `sudo su` beforehand so that you're already logged as supe user before running `create-react-app`